# What are purposes of these things that I found buried?

Tags: drainage

Ive been trying to install some rainwater drainage pipes, so I’ve been digging a lot lately. I’ve uncovered a few things--I hope that they’re either not critical or that I’m not disturbing them.

First, what is the purpose of this plastic sheet? Is this to prevent rainwater dripping from the roof to the foundation? I've also stumbled upon plastic sheets over by some french drains on the other side of the house, far away from the foundation.

In the same picture, is that an old drainage pipe? It looks like terracota, but I'm not sure why the flared out end is just hanging out underneath the porch.

[image]

Here's the last one. What's this flat metal bar laid down flat? Is it just trash? I know I have to be careful around here because this is where my gas line is coming from. However, its only an inch or so buried. I thought gas lines have to be about a foot underground.

[image]

Comment: Please upload larger photos. I can't see much in those thumbnails.

Comment: I doubt you mean "prevent rainwater ... to be diverted away from the foundation". You might revise to clarify that. If anything, it would be _intended_ to divert water away.

Comment: The piece of metal probably just some forgotten junk, not something to do with gas line.

Comment: First picture seems to show old drain tile.  It's probably wrecked and if it does anything, it's soaking the foundation.  Ideally, you want to pull it out but that might be easier said than done.

Comment: The old drainage tile was **very likely connected to the gutter downspout** at some point in time. It may or may not be functional (not good to assume anything old can't be working, or can't be restored to working, without at least *looking.*) Could be broken, could be intact but plugged with debris, could be cleanable.

Comment: The last family buried there cat and put the plastic there to keep the stink down I almost agree with jimmy and Ecnerwal most of the old homes with this age tiles are full of dirt, gravel from shingles, decomposed leaves and when roots and cracks form dirt gets in.

Comment: @EdBeal I have flushed out old tile lines - that were indeed full of dirt and crud when I found them. After flushing them out they drained water again just fine.